# Не устанавливается apk

Tags: android, apk

В Android Studio выбираю build-конфигурацию Release, потом делаю `Build APK(s)` и полученный apk заливаю на гугл-диск. После этого с телефона захожу на гугл-диск и пытаюсь установить приложение. Получаю ошибку

> Приложение не установлено.

Build и перезаливку на диск делал несколько раз - эффект тот же.

Потом выбрал build-конфигурацию Debug, перезалил еще раз и все установилось.

Вопрос номер раз - почему так происходит? И второе - есть ли где-то на андроиде детальные логи установки, чтобы можно было посмотреть на причину ошибки?

Comment: Удалял дебаг версию с телефона, перед установкой релизной?

Comment: Все логи в LogCat - смотрите по тегам `PackageManager`, `PackageInstaller`, может ещё каким-то. Главное включить отображение всех логов (`Show only selected application` поменять на `No filters`)

Comment: @Михаил на телефоне не было установлено никаких версий

Comment: @woesss Я правильно понимаю, что эти логи нужно смотреть в Android Studio при подключении телефона по USB? А на автономном телефоне эти логи недоступны?

Comment: Без рута скорее всего недоступны. Хотя лучше попробовать - в маркете есть аппы для просмотра логов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `Build APK(s)` использует настройки подписи из `gradle.build`, которых у вас там нет и APK создаётся без подписи.
Дебаг версия по-умолчанию подписывается дебажным ключом, если не задано иное.
Соответственно вам нужно [настроить подпись в `gradle.build`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#gradle_signing) (можно через диалог Project Structure),
либо подписать готовый APK из [командной строки](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#sign_manually),
либо собрать через меню `Build->Generate Signed Bundle / APK...`

Comment: А откуда этот дебажный ключ появляется? Android Studio сама генерирует? Я никакого упоминания о нем не вижу.

Comment: Да, студия генерирует дебажный ключ при первой необходимости. Он лежит в папке пользователя по пути `.android/debug.keystore`